# Why do civs request deals that they won't accept?

Tags: civilization-6

I've noticed a lot of AI civilizations requesting trades with me that they will not accept with a flavor text saying something like "I cannot accept this deal." Sometimes hitting the button for make the trade more equitable will make them accept the deal they offer, but other times they will want me to give them a bunch of things to satisfy them. Is this a known bug, or just a weird quirk due to AI's not being human?

Comment: In Civ V this sometimes happens with trade deals that have expired and need to be renewed. In that game the flavour text will be slightly different when that happens. I haven't played Civ VI yet, but are you sure this is different from that?

Comment: @sumurai8 I never played civ v.

Comment: The worst deal in history.

Comment: I don't know if it is much of a satisfying answer but it could be a couple things. 1) You've had an ongoing deal they want to renew, but their opinion of you has changed or things are worth more, so they have auto sent a renewal but in reality won't accept until it's improved. 2) Sometimes they just send absurd things because they outright dislike you. It is just a habit of the AI. -- Otherwise there isn't much to it. It's been that way since Civ V and doesn't come across as a bug honestly.